# JavaScript setInterval, Returning Functions, Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to have JavaScript rerun a specific function at a set interval with the `setInterval` function.

```
return document.getElementById('world').innerHTML = document.getElementById('world').innerHTML + "<div id='" + this.characterName + "' style='top:" + this.y * 32 + "px; left:" + this.x * 32 + "px'></div>";}
```

Previously the function didn't return anything, it just called the `getElementById` method and modified the element.  When calling the function `setInterval` did nothing.  After changing the function to return the `getElementById` method it modifies the element once, then starts returning an error in the console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Looking at the source the errors are referencing, I'm not seeing additional `<`'s, and all `<`'s in the code are within quotes properly from what I can tell.  Any ideas why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Please provide additional context to your code snippet. Often times the issue is further up in the code than the actual reported line.

Comment: There's no `setInterval()` in the code you posted.

Comment: your code doesn't make sense. Please post more code.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with the scope of the setInterval method.  I didn't realize it automatically looked to the scope of window when referring to this.  The solution was to call a function which called itself, passing the current object in as a parameter.

```
setTimeout(
            (function(self) {
                return function() {
                    self.originalFunction();
                }
            })(exampleobject), 3000
            );
```